# I need help to compute limit of exponentials

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Im trying to compute this limit 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-itn^{1/4}}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}e^{i\frac{t}{n^{1/4}}} \right)^{n} $$
Note: ($t$ is real)

I have tried to expand $$e^{i\frac{t}{n^{1/4}}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{it}{n^{1/4}}\right)^{k}\frac{1}{k!}=1+\frac{it}{n^{1/4}}-\frac{t^{2}}{2n^{1/2}}+O\left(\frac{t^{3}}{n^{3/4}}\right) $$

Which gives me $$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-itn^{1/4}}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1+\frac{it}{n^{1/4}}-\frac{t^{2}}{2n^{1/2}}+O(\frac{t^{3}}{n^{3/4}})\right)\right)^{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-itn^{1/4}} \left(1+\frac{it}{n^{3/4}}-\frac{t^{2}}{2n}+O\left(\frac{t^{3}}{n^{5/4}} \right) \right)^{n} $$
Im stuck here, and also not even sure if Im using the big O notation correctly (or maybe if its even more practical to use little O, instead ? )

Anyhow the answer is $e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}$, I appreciate help.

Comment: I've obtained 1 by a first order expansion.

Comment: try assuming it=1

Comment: post here the evaluation by wolfram

Comment: I can't read it, post directly in the OP.

Comment: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+n+goes+to+infinity+of+e%5E(-i*t*(n%5E(1%2F4)))(1-(1%2Fsqrt(n))%2B(1%2Fsqrt(n))(e%5E(i*t*n%5E(-1%2F4))))%5En)

Comment: @gimusi Is it readable?

Comment: Yes and you are right, it seems that the limit is different, I check again my work

Comment: Oh yes I've found the mistake! I will revise my answer.

Comment: This is a very good example for the importance to use little-o or big-o notation instead of asymptotics since we can get easily wrong with the order!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$e^{i\frac{t}{n^{1/4}}}=1+i\frac{t}{n^{1/4}}-\frac{t^2}{2n^{1/2}}+o(n^{-1/2})$$

*[Note that the previous error was here, indeed we need an order 2 since later we need to multiply by n obtaining a term o(1)]*

then

$$1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}e^{i\frac{t}{n^{1/4}}}= 1+i\frac{t}{n^{3/4}}-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o(1/n)$$

and

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}e^{i\frac{t}{n^{1/4}}} \right)^{n}=e^{n\log\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}e^{i\frac{t}{n^{1/4}}} \right)}= e^{n\log\left(1+i\frac{t}{n^{3/4}}-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o(1/n)\right)}=e^{n\left(i\frac{t}{n^{3/4}}-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o(1/n)\right)}= e^{itn^{1/4}-\frac{t^2}{2}+\color{red}{o(1)}}$$

and

$$e^{-itn^{1/4}}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}e^{i\frac{t}{n^{1/4}}} \right)^{n}= e^{-itn^{1/4}}e^{itn^{1/4}-\frac{t^2}{2}+o(1)}=e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}+o(1)}\to e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$$

Comment: This is was also how I approached the problem first, but according to Wolframalpha the answer is $e^{-t^{2}/2}$ ?

Comment: Ah okay that was the error. But I have like no clue how to apply little O , except that if $f(x)\in o(g(x))$ then $lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$.
In your first line, does the little O notation mean that $\frac{e^{i\frac{t}{n^{1/4}}}}{n^{-1/2}}$ goes to 0? And how did you pick the order?

Comment: @99ghegh I'm confortable with little-o notation but you can also use big-O notation. At first it isnot easy in this case what order we need but using little-o or big-O notation we can see that first order doesn't work but second order is good since in my case I obtain a term $o(1)\to 0$ and thus is negligible. With tha asymptotics way in the first solution I can't recognize the mistake since I didn't use the littel-o notation.

Comment: Okay, but I wanna learn the little O usage, in your first line does $o(n^{-1/2})$ mean that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{e^{i\frac{t}{n^{1/4}}}}{n^{-1/2}}$ goes to 0?

Comment: And what made you pick $o(n^{-1/2})$?

Comment: @99ghegh regarding little-o notation the general definition is for $x\to x_0 \qquad f(x)=o(g(x)) \iff f(x)=\omega(x)g(x)$ with $\omega(x)\to 0$ that is almost equivalent to $lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$.

Comment: @99ghegh In little-o notation the expansion for $e^x \qquad x\to 0$ is $$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+o(x^2)$$

Comment: @99ghegh jus thake $x=\frac1{n^{1/4}}\implies o(x^2)=o(n^{-1/2)}$ is it clear?

Comment: Hm I see, although Im having a hard time grasping the $o(x^{2})$, does it basically mean that it decays to 0 faster than all the other terms ($\frac{x^{3}}{6}+\frac{x^{4}}{24}+\dots$) ?

Comment: @99ghegh Yes exactly $o(x^2)$ means something wich tend to zero faster than $x^2$ terms. For example $x^{2.00001}=o(x^2)$.

Comment: Okay, also in the step where we go from $e^{n\log\left(1+i\frac{t}{n^{3/4}}-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o(1/n)\right)}$ to $e^{n\left(i\frac{t}{n^{3/4}}-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o(1/n)\right)}$ havent we taken the limit once? Since we are using $\ln(1+x)=x$ when $\lim_{x\to 0}$? Then in the last step we are taking the limit again? Is this allowed  to take the limit twice, or have I missunderstood it?

Comment: @99ghegh No we are not taking the limit we are using taylor expansion for $\log(1+x)=x+o(x)$.

Comment: @99ghegh to be more clear I'will change also the last step

Comment: Ah okay, so $ln\left(1+i\frac{t}{n^{3/4}}-\frac{t^{2}}{2n}+o(1/n)\right)=i\frac{t}{n^{3/4}}-\frac{t^{2}}{2n}+o(1/n)+o(1/n^{3/4})=i\frac{t}{n^{3/4}}-\frac{t^{2}}{2n}+o(1/n)$ ?I

Comment: @99ghegh as you can see we take the limit only in the last step

Comment: @99ghegh Yes exactly!

Comment: Okay I think I got a better understanding of it now, but lastly in the absolute last step, why does $o(1)$ vanish?

Comment: By definition $o(1)=1 \cdot \omega(x)$ with $\omega(x)\to 0$.

Comment: And this result is independent of the original limit when $n$ goes to $\infty$ or are we applying the original limit here?

Comment: @99ghegh Oh yes sorry mine is  a sort of short notation that is natural to use when we  get an advanced level with limits. Of course we are taking the limit for $n\to \infty$. Note that in this case o(1) represent a term like $\frac1{n^a}$ with $a>0$.Can you see why? Look at how we have obtained it.

Comment: Hm, maybe because $o(1/n)$ decays faster to $0$ than terms of the form $\frac{1}{n^{a}}$ where $a>0$?
Multiplying with $n$, gives $o(1)$ which has terms of the form $\frac{1}{n^{a-1}}$, where maybe some terms have exponent $a-1>0$?

Comment: @99ghegh $o(1/n)$ is a term like $\frac1{n^{1.000001}}$ thus $no(1/n)$ is a term like $\frac1{n^{0.000001}}$

Comment: Okay, thanks very much for your help and effort. I will try to see if I can learn more about the usage of little O in limits..

Comment: @99ghegh You are welcome! It was a very interesting limit and I see that you have really a nice and deep approach to it. I'm sure you will learn suddenly about this kind of notation. Bye